# Creating a bar chart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm trying to create a bar chart using d3 and here's my code, for some reason, the bar chart won't show up and I'm getting an error saying:
remote-work.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined
at drawBars (remote-work.js:14)

Can anyone advise me on where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
async function drawBars() {

// 1. Access data

const data = await d3.csv("./../remote_work.csv")
    console.log(data);

//chart = {
const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom

const x = d => d.Benefits
const y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(height, 0);

const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")

const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Benefits; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Percentage; })]);

svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Percentage ($)");

svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Benefits); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Percentage); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Percentage); });


}
drawBars()
```

Comment: It looks like your code is using version 3 of d3's API, while it sounds like the library you're using is newer than that. You can try to either download/use d3v3 from someplace like https://unpkg.com/d3@3 or rewrite your code to use the newer API

Comment: thank you Steve, I am using the newest version of d3 API and still getting the same error: https://d3js.org/

Comment: Hi soha, for your code, I think you actually need to use an older version of the library (version 3), which you can get from https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js or https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

Comment: I've updated my code and I'm still not seeing a bar chart, i don't really understand where I'm going wrong, this time I'm having no errors

Comment: Could you include your data, or at least a section of your data? It'd be easier to debug with it